# How to put a canvas on an image?

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem for today, I try to draw something on an <**img**> this is a structure

```
<div id='...' style='position:relative;'>
  <img id='...' style='posistion:absolute;' />
  <canvas id ='...' style='position:absolute;' />
</div>
```

img in css has already

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

How can i draw a canvas ON the image? For now it go behind. I can't use z-index on canvas. I tried making other divs. It has to be an img. Should i use something else instead of canvas? I could use other div but the paths i want to draw are not really simple and has to be resizable when image is bigger/smaller and still look fine.
Thanks in advice, hope everyone understood my english.

to make it more clear what i want here is a code when canvas is behind. When I prepend not append canvas an image is gone. I want to put a path to show user that this is already deleted but there are sometimes on this screen many other divs so i want to put canvas on a IMG or a DIV the img is in. It has to be in front of because when img is large we will not see path under. Here is a link
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6421191/canvasbehind.jpg

Comment: Set the image as a background image on the `div` instead. Or draw the image directly on the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id='mydiv' >
  <img id='myimage' src="http://placekitten.com/200/385" />
  <canvas id ='mycanvas'  width="200" height="100" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#mydiv{
    position: relative;
}
#myimage{
     position: relative;
}
#mycanvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

I think this is what you are trying do.

Have one image on the background and display the canvas area on top of the image?

I hope my little sample code helps you out.

Comment: nope, right now it looks like:
IMG
CANVAS
canvas is under img.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nytrm/w3XXS/ it is working for me in jsfiddle, can you share some code to see if something else is messing it up? :)

Comment: yes mate, I had a little mistake . It work fine now thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just draw your image onto the canvas:

```
<html>
<canvas id ='your_canvas'  width="1000" height="1000"/>
</html>

<script>
window.onload=function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('your_canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = (your image source);
ctx.drawImage(img, x_pos,y_pos,width,height);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Place your canvas before the img in your html:

```
<div id='...' style='position:relative;'>
<canvas id ='...' style='position:absolute;' />
<img id='...' style='posistion:absolute;' />
</div>
```

Comment: that cause that i see my path but do not see an image.